# XML-DTD help/clarification needed

Tags: xml, dtd

I've written the following DTDs for the XML file below. After checking it says it's valid, however, I'm a bit concerned since this is my very first DTD and I'm not sure if it's actually valid or not. 
Can someone tell me if it's correct?
Thanks!

DTD file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE articles [
 <!ELEMENT articles (article+)>
 <!ELEMENT article (authors+,journal+)>
 <!ELEMENT authors (author+)>
 <!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT journal (name+, volume?,issue?,published+,url?,pages?)>
 <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT issue (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT published (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT volume (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT pages (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT url (#PCDATA)>

 <!ATTLIST article title CDATA #REQUIRED id ID #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST pages start CDATA #REQUIRED end CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST url href CDATA #REQUIRED>

 ]>
```

XML File:

```
 <articles>
<article title="Computing" id="a1">
    <authors>
        <author>Fhilbertie</author>
        <author>Alicen</author>
        <author>PeDra</author>
    </authors>
    <journal>
        <name>Journals</name>
        <volume>5</volume>
        <issue>6</issue>
        <published>06/11/2013</published>
        <pages start="52" end="79"/>
    </journal>
</article>

<article title="Instruction Sets: Free Will?" id="a2">
    <authors>
        <author>Sallie</author>
        <author>Philber</author>
    </authors>
    <journal>
        <name>Metaphysics</name>
        <volume>5</volume>
        <issue>6</issue>
        <published>06/26/2015</published>
        <pages start="366" end="366"/>
    </journal>
</article>

<article title="My Journy" id="a3">
    <authors>
        <author>Lawrence</author>
    </authors>
    <journal>
        <name>M Magic</name>
        <volume>6</volume>
        <issue>4</issue>
        <published>11/12/1988</published>
    </journal>
</article>

<article title="RDF Triples and the Path to Human Subjugation" id="a4">
    <authors>
        <author>Allison Peony</author>
        <author>Robert Zephyr</author>
        <author>Sally Piper</author>
    </authors>
    <journal>
        <name>Journal of Nefarious Artificial Intelligence</name>
        <published>05/25/2006</published>
        <url href="http://example.com/rdf-triples-subjugation"/>
    </journal>
</article>

<article title="Marksideways, a Markdown Alternative" id="a5">
    <authors>
        <author>Gerald Quinoa</author>
        <author>P. von Cookie</author>
    </authors>
    <journal>
        <name>Marvelous Markup Magic</name>
        <volume>13</volume>
        <issue>3</issue>
        <published>03/14/2013</published>
        <url href="http://example.com/marksidways"/>
    </journal>
</article>

<article title="Hills" id="a6">
    <authors>
        <author>Robert Z</author>
        <author>Leonard P</author>
    </authors>
    <journal>
        <name>Journal Intelligence</name>
        <published>05/25/2014</published>
        <url href="http://example.com/hill"/>
    </journal>
</article>
```

Comment: "I get a lot of errors" is not a useful problem description. Please [edit] your question, provide a **specific** explanation of the problem you're having, and ask a **specific** question about that problem. "This doesn't work. I get errors. Please help!" is not a valid question here.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but the errors I get are a lot, and seem to be chained. I've edited the most common reasons for that errors.

Comment: Start with the very first one: "attributes aren't declared for some of the elements". You have two elements that have attributes in your XML (article title and pages start and end), and none of those attributes are described in your DTD. So fix those errors, and see how many of the others go away. It's important to actually *read the words in the error messages** - they usually have information that is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll look into the syntax of it. What about the <url>?

Comment: @Lunakai `url` is required acording to DTD but missing in your XML.

Comment: What about the URL? You declared it as being a required element of journal, but don't have it in the XML for journal. *Read the error messages, and look at what you have in front of you* - if you had, you'd see that the DTD has a URL required but you haven't included it in the corresponding XML.

Comment: @lexicore it exists in the full XML file, I just edited my question and included the other lines in which it exists.

Comment: @Lunakai So we are to guess what else you may or may not edited out.

Comment: @lexicore I apologize, but i forgot to include it in the post. Your help is much appreciated thank you.

Comment: @lexicore I have posted my whole work, it's validated on oxygen, but I still doubt my work to be correct since it's my very first DTD file. Can you please look at it and tell me what you think? Thank you again.

Comment: @Lunakai And your errors?

Comment: @lexicore I was able to eliminate them, and the document (according to Oxgen) is valid. Above is my full DTD work for the XML file below. 
Since this is my first DTD attempt, I'd like to know if my DTDs are actually correct for that XML file. Can you please see it?
Again, thanks for your time!

Comment: If the XML validates against the DTD, it's valid against that DTD. There's no point in posting it all here and asking us to repeat that validation. We're not your personal assistants. If you have a new, separate question, create a new post and ask a new, separate question.

Comment: @KenWhite As the question is posed now, it actually looks quite valid. Offtopic here but suitable for code reviews.

Comment: @lexicore Thank you. I'm new here, and  an amature developer, I hope I didn't sound like I was forcing anyone to do something they don't want to do.

Comment: @Lunakai No problem, and for your first question you did quite good. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The main problem was that you were asking for help but did not provide relevant information, like how your XML looks like and what the errors are etc. Next, after you've got rid of errors, you edited the question changing focus from "why do I get errors" to "is this DTD valid for this XML" which is a different question.

Comment: @lexicore: Yes, I've seen this question evolve (as you can see from the revision history and the comments). It's now gone from "can you fix the errors I'm not going to tell you about" to "can you re-validate my XML against my DTD because I don't trust the software or website that says it's valid", which is a totally separate question. And I don't see "Perform XML/DTD validations for you" in the list of on-topic questions in the [help]. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I totally agree on the question evolution as well as off-topic points (I basically said so above). However I think the question is not about "validate this for me" but rather "does this DTD make sense for this XML", which is more like a code review request (I know, I know, more suitable for the other site) and a different story. At least that was my interpretation.
To sum up, for the first-time poster it's not bad at all, from my POV.

Comment: @lexicore: Yes, it's gotten much better than what was originally posted. It's not a bad time for a new user to learn that they can't change the meaning of questions in mid-stream as well. (I'm not sure it's appropriate for Code Review, either - I don't think "re-confirm my XML validates" is on-topic there either according to their guidelines.)

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the DTD and the XML. Looks quite fine for me, at least syntactically.
(This is the answer to your question.)

Few hints:

- If you want an elaborate review, consider posting it on the https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (make sure you read and comply to the rules there).
- Why DTD? Quite outdated, consider using an XML Schema.
- Search for other schemas in this area. BibTeXML is one of the things I heard of, but there must be tons of them. Check what big resources use.

Comment: Thank you!
I'm using DTD since it's part of my learning process, I just started with Markup languages. I'll make sure I follow the guidelines next time. You've been very supportive, Thank you!